# how to set a variable of a class from an other file in python

Tags: python, class

Let's define two files :

test1.py

```
import test2

def doit():
    test2.var.a = 5
```

test2.py

```
class toto:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 10
        self.c = 0

    def func(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print(self.c)

global var
var = toto()
def main():

    print('start')
    var.func() # compute 1 + 10 = 11
    test1.doit() # change value of a
    var.func() # shall compute 5 + 10 = 15 but still 11

    r=1 #for breakpoint


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I do not achieve to set the variable var.a from test1.py. It sounds like the class is duplicated in memory rather than adressing the one already instantiated.
Any idea ?

thanks & cheers

Stephane

Comment: If you run `test2.py` directly, then the module that is running is not named `test2` - it's named `__main__` (if it wasn't, then `main()` would not get called).  Doing `import test2` creates an entirely separate module, with its own instance of `var`.

Comment: Which file do you run? How can test2.py access test1.py if you don't import it?

Comment: As an aside, `global var` is completely pointless, just remove it.

Comment: The solution here is to move the drive code to a separate module.

Comment: Yes there is an import test1 in test2. Just a copy and paste mistake.
I run test2 which runs main

I don't get the comment "The solution here is to move the drive code to a separate module". Does it mean to move what is inside mainà into a separate module ? What is the difference ?

Comment: @jasonharper.  Do I understand that it the presence of if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() tells to the compiler that the module is actually named main ?
Does it mean I've to do an import main ?

Comment: it is not good idea to assing value in this way. You should rather define `def doit(item):    item.a = 5` and later run it as `test1.doit(var)`

Comment: No, it's the other way around - the script you run is automatically named `__main__`,  that `if __name__...` test is checking whether this is the top-level script, versus an imported file.

Comment: @jasonharper 
ok thanks but how can I then import a variable from the module including the if --name-- ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong idea to change value in this way.

You should send object `explicitly` as argument - and then you don't need to import, and code is more readable, and it is also simpler to debug.

And this is suggested by [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): `"Explicit is better than implicit."`

```
def doit(item):
    item.a = 5
```

and later

```
doit(var)
```

---

**test1.py**

```
# no need to import

def doit(item):
    item.a = 5
```

**test2.py**

```
import test1

class Toto:  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 10
        self.c = 0

    def func(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print(self.c)

def main():
    var = Toto()

    print('start')

    var.func()  # compute 1 + 10 = 11
    doit(var)   # change value of a
    var.func()  # shall compute 5 + 10 = 15 but still 11

    r = 1  # for breakpoint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: yes this works fine like this... and avoid global var...
thanks